# Contstraint stream breaks when switching from OptaPlanner 7.46.0 to 8.0.0

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I have a constraint that crashes in the latest OptaPlanner 8.0.0, but used to work fine on 7.46.0.
As expected, IntelliJ's code inspection (and the debugger) shows that after the first join, the stream is a `TriConstraintStream`. The runtime class makes more sense to me than the class OptaPlanner is trying to cast to.
When leaving out the last `groupBy` the error goes away, so that clause seems to cause the issue.

Did something change in the way join and groupby worked?
It seems that the underlying OptaPlanner code was refactored for 8.0.0, so I have trouble seeing what exactly changed in OptaPlanner.
Should I add something to ensure that a TriJoin is used instead of a BiJoin?
I could not find any relevant notes in the migration documentation.

```java
protected Constraint preventProductionShortage(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Demand.class)
            .groupBy(Demand::getSKU,
                    Demand::getWeekNumber
            )//BiConstraintStream
            .join(Demand.class,
                    equal((sku, weekNumber)-> sku, Demand::getSKU),
                    greaterThanOrEqual((sku, weekNumber)-> weekNumber, Demand::getWeekNumber)//TriConstraintStream
            )
            .groupBy((sku, weekNumber, totalDemand) -> sku,
                    (sku, weekNumber, totalDemand) -> weekNumber,
                    sum((sku, weekNumber, totalDemand) -> totalDemand.getOrderQuantity())
            )//TriConstraintStream
            .penalize("Penalty", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM,
                    (sku_weekNumber, demandQty, productionQty) -> 1);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.tri.CompositeTriJoiner cannot be cast to class org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.bi.AbstractBiJoiner (org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.tri.CompositeTriJoiner and org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.bi.AbstractBiJoiner are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.rules.BiJoinMutator.<init>(BiJoinMutator.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.rules.UniRuleAssembler.join(UniRuleAssembler.java:70)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.rules.AbstractRuleAssembler.join(AbstractRuleAssembler.java:179)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.ConstraintSubTree.getRuleAssembler(ConstraintSubTree.java:94)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.ConstraintSubTree.getRuleAssembler(ConstraintSubTree.java:89)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.ConstraintGraph.generateRule(ConstraintGraph.java:431)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.ConstraintGraph.lambda$generateRule$57(ConstraintGraph.java:423)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.ConstraintGraph.generateRule(ConstraintGraph.java:424)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintFactory.buildSessionFactory(DroolsConstraintFactory.java:101)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.ConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(ConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:77)
    at org.optaplanner.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultConstraintVerifier.verifyThat(DefaultConstraintVerifier.java:63)
    at org.optaplanner.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultConstraintVerifier.verifyThat(DefaultConstraintVerifier.java:32)
    at com.ohly.planner.constraints.ConstraintsTest.weekShortageSingleSKU(ConstraintsTest.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

[edit] For completeness, the new function as suggested by [Lukáš Petrovický](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051916/contstraint-stream-breaks-when-switching-from-optaplanner-7-46-0-to-8-0-0/65092499#65092499)

```
    protected Constraint preventProductionShortage(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.from(Demand.class)
                .join(Demand.class,
                        equal(Demand::getSKU),
                        greaterThanOrEqual(demand -> demand.getWeekNumber()))
                .groupBy((d, d2) -> d.getSKU(),
                        (d, d2) -> d.getWeekNumber(),
                        sum((d,d2) -> d2.getOrderQuantity())
                )
                ...
```

[/edit]

Comment: Hey there, this looks to me to be a bug. I'll look into it. 
EDIT: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [unfortunate bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2270) not caught by the existing test coverage.
[The fix](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/1056) is aimed at OptaPlanner 8.0.1, incl. test coverage improvement.

That said, I would argue that the constraint is not very efficient. Unless I'm missing some key implications, the following is semantically very similar, yet much faster:

```
protected Constraint preventProductionShortage(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Demand.class)
        .join(Demand.class,
                equal(Demand::getSKU),
                greaterThanOrEqual(demand -> demand.getWeekNumber()))
        .groupBy(..., ..., sum((demand, demand2) -> ...))
        .penalize("Penalty", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM);
```

}

Note how I eliminated the first use of `groupBy()`. There may be some difference though in how many tuples are penalized this way, which may or may not be what you want. Feel free to open another question on that.

Comment: I spent some time debugging and figured that this was probably a bug, but was unable to grok the code enough to be sure. Thanks for the quick response!  

The suggestion on the constraint was also very helpful, since I did this pattern four times in my constraints. The code now runs 15x as fast (though the `group(...)` that remained needed editing since it now gets `(Demand, Demand)` as input)  and the tests are still green :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the change in inputs - I have updated the answer a bit to not be confusing, without actually having the type signatures at hand. :-)